# Calulate number of days between datetimes

Tags: matlab, datetime, diff

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two `datetime`s in MATLAB.

```
startDate = datetime('12-Nov-2014 00:00:00','InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
endDate = datetime('18-Feb-2016 00:00:00','InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Using `diff` I get the following result:

```
diff([startDate endDate])

ans = 

   11112:00:00
```

I am expecting a value of about `500` days not `11000`.

Comment: The result is in hours.

Comment: use `daysact` for days (which does leap year for you) http://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/daysact.html

Comment: @GameOfThrows `daysact` is a toolbox function, use [`between`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/between.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can avoid to use `datetime`:

```
startDate = datenum('12-Nov-2014 00:00:00');
endDate = datenum('18-Feb-2016 00:00:00');

days = endDate-startDate

days = 
      463
```

Comment: because it works..

Comment: This works fine! The problem with hours is that i cannot be sure of the number of days. I used this command: datenum(endDate)-datenum(startDate)